# When we call a function from a module, there is only comments inside the function, so how exactly the function realize its functionalitly?

Tags: python, function, built-in

Where is the real place store the code for the realization of the functionality?

[image]

Comment: Please enter the code using a code block instead of an image. This makes it easier to see (because we don't have to click a link) and allows a search engine or other users to find it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? There is not *only comments*, but also a `return 0` statement.

Comment: This function is implemented in [C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/sysmodule.c#L1681)

Comment: intellij is lying to you.

Answer (score 1):

The function in fact has some functionality. The last line is: `return 0`. I would assume this method is ment to be overridden by a subclass to implement some actually useful code.